# New Zoom H2 Windshield (the one it comes with)?

Tags: zoom, h2, windshield, replacement-parts

Hi All,

Today I got my hands on a Rycote windjammer for the H2. Roughly 10 minutes after trying it out I seem to have lost my original windshield that came with it! Typical :/ Searched high and low to the point of almost losing my sanity but can't locate it anywhere. The Rycote works best over the top of the original windshield but as I seem to have lost it I was wondering where I could pick up another? Or does anyone have a spare lying around? ;)

Any help much appreciated! 
Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

Rode Dead Kitten fits fine.

http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/DeadKitten

Answer (score 0):

I'd contact Samson. I've not seen the foam windscreens around for sale. I don't use my H2 anymore, but I'm keeping my foamy bits...they fit perfectly over the Senny MD421! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Contact Samson directly, they are really friendly and sell spare parts for the H2.  My students regularly break the SD card slot covers and the replacements arrive next day from Samson in the UK.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! lol I think I managed to break mine off in about 3 days of getting it. Hopefully they'll have all the bits in stock..

Answer (score 0):

Wander into your local music store and look for a [Microphone Windscreen](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Musician-s-Gear-Microphone-Windscreen-421657-i1400374.gc).  The come in different sizes and should slip on over the top of the H2.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this figured out by now since this was asked a while ago but B&H sell it and since it is virtually weightless I am guessing shipping would be pretty cheap if you don't live near by.

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/703336-REG/Zoom_S_SP02691_Foam_Windscreen_for_H2.html

Comment: I actually managed to find it again! Typically once I'd ordered for a replacement though lol